# How to write a SQL query for the below?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with n of columns from `Col1` to `Col30`

`Table 1`.

```
  Templateid    Col1            Col2    Col3     Col4  ...
  95            2019-05-28      1234    test123  123456
```

`Table 2`.

```
Templateid  DisplayName ColumnName
95          date            col1
95          rank            col2
95          purpose         col3
95          sign            col4
```

Expected Results.

```
Col1Name  Col1Value   Col2Name  Col2Value Col3Name  Col3Value ....
date      2019-05-28  rank      1234      purpose   test123
```

Comment: `PIVOT` and `JOIN` will do the work, google it :)

Comment: Or you could look up "cross tab", there are plenty of examples on the internet, and SO, of both options. Please do have a look and show your attempts if you fail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a crude way of doing it and if you do not know the number of columns in each table you would need to use dynamic sql to enumerate them out but for the purposes of this example I have assumed you do know the number of columns and the names you want to populate.

The union query allows you to pre-populate the desired column names using the col1 syntax, then the pivot allows you to match up the displaynames and the display values. A case statement is required to ensure the correct values are shown and you do need to populate your derived column names for the pivot query but you do get the desired outcome this way.

```
declare @table1 table (
    Templateid int,
    Col1 date,
    col2 int,
    col3 nvarchar(10),
    col4 int
);

insert into @table1 (Templateid, col1, col2, col3, col4)
values
(95, '2019-05-28', '1234', 'test123', '123456');


declare @table2 table (
    Templateid int,
    Displayname nvarchar(10),
    ColumnName nvarchar(10)
);

insert into @table2 (Templateid, Displayname, ColumnName)
values
(95, 'date', 'col1'),
(95, 'rank', 'col2'),
(95, 'purpose', 'col3'),
(95, 'sign', 'col4');


select * from
(
select columnname+'Name' as columnname, Displayname 
from @table2 t2
union
select columnname+'Value', case when columnname='col1' then cast(col1 as nvarchar(15)) 
                                when columnname='col2' then cast(col2 as nvarchar(15)) 
                                when columnname='col3' then cast(col3 as nvarchar(15)) 
                                when columnname='col4' then cast(col4 as nvarchar(15)) end
from @table1 t1 inner join @table2 t2 on t1.Templateid=t2.Templateid) src
pivot
(max(displayname) for columnname in ([col1Name],[col1Value], [col2Name],[col2Value], [col3Name],[col3Value], [col4Name],[col4Value])) piv;
```